# Improve R2 by removing outliers-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am using the following code to find out Linregress parameters:

```
import numpy, scipy,pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.stats import linregress
import scipy.stats
import copy
df=pd.read_excel("S:/Python/Excel.xlsx")
df.head();
xyDataPairs = df[['x', 'y']].values.tolist();
df.groupby('Test Event',as_index=True)['x', 'y'].apply(linregress)
res= df.groupby('Test Event',as_index=True)['x', 'y'].apply(linregress);
print(res)
res.to_excel('result.xlsx')
```

From this I get all linregress parameters (Slope, intercept, R2, pvalue and stderror)

#### #

The challenge for me starts here:

I need to use Python to remove Outliers from a dataset inorder to improve the R2 (which will result in a corresponding change in slope). Post removing the outliers, I then need to calculate the modified linregress parameters(slope, intercept, R2, pvalue and std error) per sequence.

Say when an outlier was not removed, R2=0.721 but on removing an outlier, the resulting R2 is 0.852

The data table is as follows:

[image: Dataset]

I have 10 data points per sequence (A,B and C) and need to remove outliers present in each sequence. The outliers are highlighted in 'yellow' in the dataset. I have also given the output data which has outliers removed.

When we remove these outliers, R2, slope, intercept etc change.

How do I go about doing this using Python? Any help on this is highly appreciated.

---

I asked in Crossvalidate and I was suggested to use robust regression method for this kind of analysis.

Which python libraries/packages I should use for this question?

Comment: Is your question 1) How do you identify the outliers, which is much better suited for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), or 2) Given your definition of an outlier, how does one subset a `DataFrame`, which can be answered here if you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @ALollz, for me an outlier is when the R2 value changes by more than 15%. If you think this question is better suited for Crossvalidated, I will ask it there.

Comment: I am extremely newbie in python and do not have any code for it to go with.

Comment: That's a somewhat difficult definition to implement. Looking at your data, I'd categorize those values as 'erroneous', instead of outliers. You expect some outliers in your data, but given the distribution of your other values, those 4 are just totally wrong. Those incorrect values are going to heavily skew your mean and standard deviation, so instead you could use the Median Absolute Deviation, which is more robust to that kind of error. Any reasonable threshold will catch them.

Comment: Hi ALollz, thanks for the reply, Those values are exaggerated. However, those values can be closer to other data set too. Thus need deletion whenever R2 changes by 15%.

Comment: I asked in Crossvalidate and I was suggested to use robust regression method for this kind of analysis.

Which python libraries/packages I should use for this question?

Comment: `statsmodels` is a rather powerful regression library. But it seems like it might be a bit overkill for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have value you know you want to call your "cutoff" for outliers.

```
cutoff = 100 # this is your arbitrary outlier cutoff
df = df[df[y] < cutoff]
```

This should remove all your outlier values from the dataset.

Comment: issue is there is no cutoff. Thus cannot use the cutoff method. Thanks for the reply!